# How do we calculate the primitive of $r^{3}\sqrt{r^{2} + 2}$ without guessing?

Tags: calculus, integration

I encountered the following problem:
$\int r^3 \sqrt{r^2+2}\;dr$
I found the answer to be:
$1/5(r^2+2)^{5/2}−2/3(r^2+2)^{3/2}$
Although this is the correct answer, I am not entirely sure how this works, more specifically on how you find line of equation such as in this case:
$r^3=r^2r=[(r^2+2)−2]r=(r^2+2)r−2r$
Can anyone explain how you find this value other than trial and error through testing everything you can think of?

Comment: Do you know [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Repeated_integration_by_parts)?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner No, I am only in calculus I

Comment: What integration techniques do you know other than guessing via trial and error? Integration by parts is one of the first things one learns when it comes to integration. Where did you encounter this problem? It seems to me that it might be case that you are rushing ahead of material and that you'll soon learn appropriate techniques to solve such problems.

Comment: See amWhy's or IvoTerek's answer at [Integrating $\;\int x^3\sqrt{x^2 + 2}\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973327/integrating-int-x3-sqrtx2-2-dx)

Comment: $r^3 = \frac{1}{2} 2 r^2 r$

Answer (score 2):

To follow from your line of thinking, you may consider using [u-substitution](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-integration-new/ab-6-9/a/review-applying-u-substitution). If we let $u=r^2 + 2$, then $du = 2r \ dr$. Note that
$$u = r^2 + 2 \iff u-2=r^2$$
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\int r^3 \sqrt{r^2+2}\ dr &= \int \underbrace{r^2}_{=u-2} \underbrace{\sqrt{r^2+2}}_{=\sqrt{u}} \ \underbrace{r \ dr}_{=du/2} \\
&= \int (u-2) \sqrt{u} \ \frac{1}{2}du \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int \left(u^{3/2} - 2u^{1/2}\right) du \\
&= \frac{1}{5} u^{5/2} - \frac{2}{3} u^{3/2} + C \\
&= \frac{1}{5} (r^2+2)^{5/2} - \frac{2}{3} (r^2 + 2)^{3/2} +C 
\end{align*}

This approach avoids "guessing" some way to rewrite $r^3$.

Answer (score 1):

[Integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) gives:

\begin{align*}
\int r^{3}\sqrt{r^{2} + 2}\mathrm{d}r & = \int r^{2}\left(r\sqrt{r^{2} + 2}\right)\mathrm{d}r\\\\
& = \frac{1}{3}\int r^{2}\left[(r^{2} + 2)^{3/2}\right]'\mathrm{d}r\\\\
& = \frac{1}{3}r^{2}(r^{2} + 2)^{3/2} - \frac{2}{3}\int r(r^{2} + 2)^{3/2}\mathrm{d}r\\\\
& = \frac{1}{3}(r^{2} + 2)^{5/2} - \frac{2}{3}(r^{2} + 2)^{3/2} - \frac{2}{3}\int r(r^{2} + 2)^{3/2}\mathrm{d}r\\\\
& = \left(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{2}{15}\right)(r^{2} + 2)^{5/2} - \frac{2}{3}(r^{2} + 2)^{3/2}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{5}(r^{2} + 2)^{5/2} - \frac{2}{3}(r^{2} + 2)^{3/2} + C
\end{align*}

**EDIT**

To be more precise, notice that
\begin{align*}
\int r\sqrt{r^{2} + 2}\mathrm{d}r & = \frac{1}{2}\int 2r\sqrt{r^{2} + 2}\mathrm{d}r\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int\sqrt{r^{2} + 2}\,\mathrm{d}(r^{2} + 2)\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int \sqrt{u}\,\mathrm{d}u\\\\
& = \frac{1}{3}u^{3/2} + C\\\\
& = \frac{1}{3}(r^{2} + 2)^{3/2} + C
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

**By Substitution**

Let $x=\sqrt{r^2+2}$, then $x^2=r^2+2$ and $xdx=rdr$ transforms the integral into
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int\left(x^2-2\right) x \cdot x d x \\
& =\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{2 x^3}{3}+c\\&=\frac{\left(r^2+2\right)^{\frac{5}{2}}}{5}-\frac{2\left(r^2+2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}+C\\&= \frac{1}{15}\left(r^2+2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\left(3 r^2-4\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$